# Obter caminho de rede

Tags: c#, redes

Tenho um Form que está salvo na rede que esta mapeada como `\\\\BRJGS090\suporte$` na unidade `Z:`. Este Form executa um aplicativo que está na mesma pasta através do `ProcessStartInfo`, no computador local funciona normalmente porem quando executo ele da rede diz que o aplicativo não pode ser encontrado.

Já tentei utilizar `Application.StartupPath`, `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory`, porém verifiquei que ele retorna o caminho como sendo `Z:\programas\aplicativos` que é onde o Form e o outro aplicativo estão. Há alguma forma de obter este caminho da rede como sendo `\\\\BRJGSD090\suporte$\programas\aplicativos`?

Answer (score 1):

Não existe, na implementação atual do framework, nenhuma função nativa que transforme um path em um diretório mapeado para sua URI de rede. Você pode, entretanto, implementar uma função:

```
public static class Pathing
{
    [DllImport("mpr.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int WNetGetConnection(
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string localName, 
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder remoteName, 
        ref int length);
    /// <summary>
    /// Given a path, returns the UNC path or the original. (No exceptions
    /// are raised by this function directly). For example, "P:\2008-02-29"
    /// might return: "\\networkserver\Shares\Photos\2008-02-09"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="originalPath">The path to convert to a UNC Path</param>
    /// <returns>A UNC path. If a network drive letter is specified, the
    /// drive letter is converted to a UNC or network path. If the 
    /// originalPath cannot be converted, it is returned unchanged.</returns>
    public static string GetUNCPath(string originalPath)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(512);
        int size = sb.Capacity;

        // look for the {LETTER}: combination ...
        if (originalPath.Length > 2 && originalPath[1] == ':')
        {
            // don't use char.IsLetter here - as that can be misleading
            // the only valid drive letters are a-z && A-Z.
            char c = originalPath[0];
            if ((c >= 'a' && c <= 'z') || (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z'))
            {
                int error = WNetGetConnection(originalPath.Substring(0, 2), 
                    sb, ref size);
                if (error == 0)
                {                        
                    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(originalPath);

                    string path = Path.GetFullPath(originalPath)
                        .Substring(Path.GetPathRoot(originalPath).Length);
                    return Path.Combine(sb.ToString().TrimEnd(), path);
                }
            }
        }
        return originalPath;
    }
}
```

No seu exemplo, `GetUNCPath("Z:\programas\aplicativos")` retornará a string `"\\BRJGSD090\suporte$\programas\aplicativos"`.

Fonte externa: [Converting a mapped drive letter to a network path using C#](http://www.wiredprairie.us/blog/index.php/archives/22)

Answer (score 0):

Você pode guardar o endereço em uma variável no banco ou no app.config dizendo qual o diretório que você quer trabalhar e salvar esse endereço lá.

Se for necessário, pode até criar uma tela para o usuário ou administrador alterar esse caminho.